# how to handle nested promises in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I need a solution to this below confusion i have .

#### I have a list of promises `outer_promises_list`.

#### Inside the promise.then of each promise in this `outer_promises_list` , I have another list of promises `inner_promises_list`

What I want is a method which gets called when all the outer promises and all the promises inside them get resolved .

Here is my code to get the context :

```
fetch = require("node-fetch") 

function all_promises_resolved_method() {
    console.log("All promises resolved ! ");
}


function start_main_process() {
    let outer_promises_list = []
    let inner_promises = []


    start_urls_list.forEach(url => {
        outer_promises_list.push(fetch(url).then(resp => resp.text()))
    })


    outer_promises_list.forEach((outer_prom) => 
        {
            outer_prom.then(htmlbody => 
            {

                inner_promises = inner_promises.concat(get_theater_promises());
                inner_promises.forEach(inner_prom => {
                    inner_prom.then(inner_resp => {

                        inner_resp.clone().text().then(inner_html_body => {
                            console.log("do synchronous stuff on this html body ");
                        })
                    })
                })
            })


            console.log("inner promises skipped , will be resolved later ");

            Promise.all(inner_promises.concat(outer_promises_list)).then(all_promises_resolved_method)

        })
}





function get_inner_promises() {
    inner_promises = []
        [url1, url2, url3].forEach((url)=>{

            inner_promises.push(fetch(href))

        })

return inner_promises;
}


start_main_process() ;
```

My issue is that `all_promises_resolved_method` is called only when the inner_promises of the first outer promise is resolved . I need a solution to call that method when all outer promises and each of all of those inner promises are resolved. What's the easiest way and efficient way to do this ?

Comment: What is `city_prom`? It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the rest of the code. Also, `outer_prom` is declared as an argument in the `forEach`, but never used

Comment: seems if you returned the Promise.all inside the forEach, but change the forEach to a map, and then Promise.all on the result of the map, that would be what you want

Comment: How about [chaining Promises with `.then`](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining) ?

Comment: sorry i have edited the city_prom to be outer_prom . It was a typo . Please review now .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you missed a few things in your pseudocode or there is some typo. Also, you are calling `Promise.all` on `outer_promises_list` and `inner_promises` twice, not sure why. Following is my solution, anyway.

Please remember that JS Promise is designed to avoid nested code. So if you are using promises while nesting callbacks or Promises, most likely you are not doing it right.

```
fetch = require("node-fetch")

function all_promises_resolved_method() {
    console.log("All promises resolved ! ");
}


function start_main_process() {
    let outer_promises_list = []
    let inner_promises = []

    start_urls_list.forEach(url => {
        outer_promises_list.push(fetch(url).then(resp => resp.text()))
    })


    Promise.all(outer_prom)
        .then(htmlbodyArr => {//it is an array of resolved values from all the promises in outer_prom
            /*
               I don't know how you are using htmlBody to create inner promise.
               Following is my best guess
             */

            htmlbodyArr.forEach((htmlBody)=>{
                inner_promises.push(get_theater_promises(htmlBody));
            })
            return inner_promises;
        })
        .then((inner_promises)=>{
            return Promise.all(inner_promises)
        })
        .then((innerPromiseResultArr)=>{
            all_promises_resolved_method();
        })
        .catch((err)=> console.log(err))

/*
    outer_promises_list.forEach((outer_prom) =>
    {
        outer_prom.then(htmlbody =>
        {

            inner_promises = inner_promises.concat(get_theater_promises());
            inner_promises.forEach(inner_prom => {
                inner_prom.then(inner_resp => {

                    inner_resp.clone().text().then(inner_html_body => {
                        console.log("do synchronous stuff on this html body ");
                    })
                })
            })
        })


        console.log("inner promises skipped , will be resolved later ");

        Promise.all(inner_promises.concat(outer_promises_list)).then(all_promises_resolved_method)

    })
    */
}





function get_inner_promises() {
    inner_promises = []
        [url1, url2, url3].forEach((url)=>{

        inner_promises.push(fetch(href))

    })

    return inner_promises;
}


start_main_process() ;
```